# How to use a function returned from a hook that is itself a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to apply API-first approach to developing some custom hook for polling REST API and arrived at something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <head>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root">
    </body>
    <script type="text/babel">

        const useInterval = callback => {
            const savedCallback = React.useRef();

            React.useEffect(() => {
                savedCallback.current = callback;
            }, [callback]);

            React.useEffect(() => {
                function tick() {
                    savedCallback.current();
                }
                let id = setInterval(tick, 1000);
                return () => clearInterval(id);
            }, []);
        };

        const apiHook = () => {

            const poll = () => useInterval(() => console.log('polling API'))

            return { poll }
        }

        const App = () => {

            const someApiHook = apiHook()

            return <button onClick={someApiHook.poll}>Poll API</button>
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
    </script>

</html>
```

It does not work because it breaks the very first [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). I understand that, yet what I am doing feels natural and I was wondering if there is no way of keeping such API?

Comment: `Otherwise I will need to go by the book and useInterval hook manually with useEffect` you can't use hook inside `useEffect`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, true. I deleted that part of my question as I meant something else but it is not very relevant to the question.

Comment: What is this button supposed to do really?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Upon the button click polling the backend API for task progress should start (subsequently updating some internal progress state that I skipped for clarity of the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try like this:

Hook:

```
const useInteval = (callback) => {
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  const start = useCallback(() => {
    if (intervalRef.current) return;
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(callback, 1000);
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  });

  return { start };
};
```

Usage:

```
const { start } = useInteval(() => {
  console.log("interval");
});
<button onClick={start}>Poll API</button>
```